# getJson and parse to create a list (for now) jQuery/Yahoo Finance API

Tags: jquery, getjson, yahoo-finance

I almost have the thing working but I can't get past a parsing issue. If anyone can help I would be very thankful!

I am trying to query Yahoo Finance API and parse the results using jQuery. Here is my code to do so:

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'NPO'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback";

$.getJSON(url + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});


});
</script>
```

But I am getting this error:
[image]

Any help overcoming this error would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Im sorry , I thought , I have some experience in jquery, but what does the $('<ul/>', {.... part do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `jsoncallback` parameter is not used by the service.
- You even don't have to specify `callback` parameter. It is added by the `getJSON()`
- `format` parameter is already specified in `url`
- Your `items` array is storing objects as the data are under `data.query.results.quote`

Try this:

```
var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'NPO'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(data.query.results.quote, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });
  $('<ul/>', { 'class': 'my-new-list', html: items.join('')}).appendTo('body');
});
```

Working code is **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/Tb9NG/)**.

Comment: +1 for also drilling down to the actual desired content in the response.

Answer (score 3):

YQL uses a `callback=?` parameter, not `jsoncallback=?` try this:

```
var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'NPO'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

$.getJSON(url + "&format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
```

Edit: Note, the url had to change too.

Comment: Did you try that url? Sends back an error response. `?({"error":{"lang":"en-US","diagnostics":{"publiclyCallable":"true"},"description":"Invalid JSON callback parameter ?"}});`

Comment: yes. this is what it should result in: `http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'NPO'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=foo` where foo is the callback name set by jquery

Comment: Yep, works. I didn't see that you modified the `url` string too. +1

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me when you remove the `&jsoncallback=?`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" +                    
              "q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'NPO'" + 
              "&format=json&diagnostics=true" + 
              "&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

        console.log( data );

    });
});
```

You actually already have the `format=json` in the main string.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ykkMk/)**